# Получить список, состоящий из цифр числа?

Tags: python, list

Как получить из числа `12345` список `[1,2,3,4,5]`?
UPD: Знаю, что в моем коде числа в списка будут идти в обратном порядке

```
x = int(input())
a = []
def array(x):
    while x > 0:
        b = x % 10
        a.append(b)
        x //= 10

print(array(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

надо вернуть значение из функции, а чтобы развернуть список используйте `reversed`

```
def array(x):
    a = []
    while x > 0:
        b = x % 10
        a.append(b)
        x //= 10
    return list(reversed(a))
```

Answer (score 3):

Все очень просто:

```
int = 12345
stroka = str(int)
print(stroka)
ss = list(stroka)
print(ss)
```

Comment: называть переменные именами встроенных методов - очень плохая идея. поменяйте имя `int` на что-то более правильное.